# FOSUserBundle check path blank page on production

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I have a site with FOSUserBundle. It works perfectly on both dev and prod environments on my local MAMP server. It works perfectly on my normal web server (dev and prod), but not in the other one. Recently I have uploaded my site on client's production server and I cannot login. In Dev it works, in prod it does not. There are no problems witch cache directory or logs. I get white page on /check route. It is weird cause app/check.php says that server is OK with PHP 5.6 IT work on my server but not here. Any guess how to debug it?

Comment: Do you have an accellerator running like apc? Try clearing its cache, in case of APC it would be `php -r "apc_clear_cache();"`

Also, make your app_dev.php temporarily(!) available on your prod machine, hoping that it shows some error that will help you further.

Comment: check the logs , you may also set php to display errors http://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/1545904

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have tried everything, also things proposed by @k0pernikus and @zizoujab. I have added the same logs dev has, checked server config with **app/check.php**, checked Apache errors etc. Nothing. Non of these returned any errors.

It turned out that somehow server admin has reservered **/check** path for something. We have even checked cache files with routing definitions until we got to app.php file and it turned out that script doesn't even go there in case we use **/check** path. We have checked multiple pages at the same server and everywhere the problem is the same (even on pages not made with Symfony). 
The funniest (or the worst) part of it is that for 30 minutes while talking to admin, he didn't know what is the reason for that. Still we are waiting for an answer but for now we had to change routing so that there is no **/check** path. As soon as we will receive an answer, I will post it here.

EDIT-------
It turned out that the server owner has thier API which uses /check globally. They trying to figure out if they can switch if off for user's servers.